# Overriding methods in vala

Tags: gtk3, vala

As an experiemnt, I'm extending the Gtk.HeaderBar class in vala like this, in order to have a Button instead of the title / subtitle Labels:

```
using Gtk;

public class WebBrowserHeaderBar : HeaderBar {

    private Button title_widget;

    public WebBrowserHeaderBar(){
        this.show_close_button = true;

        title_widget = new Button.with_label("title");

        this.set_custom_title(title_widget);
    }

    public void set_title(string title){
        title_widget.label = title;
    }

}
```

and then I'm using it like this:

```
public class MainWindow: Window {

    private WebBrowserHeaderBar header;

    public MainWindow() {
        //this.title = MyWeb.APP_TITLE;

        this.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
        set_default_size (300, 200);

        header = new WebBrowserHeaderBar();
        header.set_title (MyWeb.APP_TITLE);
        this.set_titlebar(header);
    }

}
```

That works, however I get the following warning while compiling:

```
WebBrowserHeaderBar.vala:15.2-15.22: warning: WebBrowserHeaderBar.set_title hides inherited method `Gtk.HeaderBar.set_title'. Use the `new' keyword if hiding was intentional
    public void set_title(string title){
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
```

If I change my method like this `public override void set_title(string title){`, it won't compile:

```
WebBrowserHeaderBar.vala:15.2-15.31: error: WebBrowserHeaderBar.set_title: no suitable method found to override
    public override void set_title(string title){
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Why am I getting this? How can I get rid of the warning and/or successfully override the `set_title` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only override methods that are `abstract` or `virtual`. Other methods cannot be overridden, but you can hide them using the `new` keyword:

```
public new void set_title (string title) {
     title_widget.label = title;
}
```

If the reference is of type `WebBrowserHeaderBar`, or one of its children, this method will be called. If the reference is of type `HeaderBar` or one of its superclasses, then the original `set_title` will be used.

This is a somewhat there-be-dragons feature.